# Literally unable to install Nvidia drivers - (the following drivers have unmet dependencies plus even more)

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, dependencies

So whenever I run `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` I get a traceback error. No big deal, I can just run `apt install nvidia-driver-525`, but in response, I get `The following packages have unmet dependencies: libglx-mesa0 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) but 22.3.0+git2212141255.6d5ce49956b~j~mesarc5 is to be installed : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`.

So I try to install `libglx-mesa0`, it’s apparently already installed

Then I try to install `libgl1-mesa-dri` which needs the libglx dependency, which as mentioned before, was already installed.

What do I do?

Comment: You've not provided your OS &  release details (*essential for fixing package issues*), but a look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libglapi-mesa&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all implies to me you've added 3rd party sources to your system that are creating the issues.  Please provide your OS & release, then maybe a `apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa` to show what 3rd party source you've added to clarify what you've done to create the issue too. *Your added sources prevent you from using `ubuntu-drivers`; flagged as duplicate for generic answer as I don't know your release*

Comment: Looks like you've added [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ernstp/+archive/ubuntu/mesarc), which, apparently, wasn't a good idea. Remove it along with all its packages.